# Django Raising Runtime Error

Tags: django, django-1.7

I got the following django error:

> "RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet."

I am using django 1.7 development version.

Comment: You can read about possible causes of it error here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-changes

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
try:
   import django
   django.setup()
except AttributeError:
   pass
```